# Move off-topic questions

Tags: feature-request, off-topic

Will there be an option to move off-topic questions to superuser when the site goes live?

There will of course from time to time come questions [like this one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/881/how-to-get-photographs-off-iphone-4-wirelessly) (where the only relation to photography is that the image files he wants to move happen to be taken with the phone camera). I would like the opportunity to send them to superuser rather than just closing them as off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this Jeff in [this thread on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan), then yes, it will be possible. I guess likely sites for us to want to migrate to are:

- [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) - Things like the linked question to do with file management/transfer, essentially.
- [The D-SLR Video proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9024/dslr-video-shooting) - Fairly obvious.
- [The Video and Film Production proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2797/video-and-film-production) - If the above doesn't take off, and for questions relating to production.
- [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) - I think there's another thread on meta.photo about flickr, for example, and questions relating to how to use flickr should probably be migrated.
- [Meta.Photo](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/) - For the inevitable meta posts that get plonked in the main site.
- [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) - Maybe we only need to migrate questions from meta.Photo, but [according to Jeff](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/#comment-48725) issues with the SE engine should end up on meta.SO.

I've made this community wiki, so people can add other sites they think it'd be good to link with.

Comment: I don't think Meta.SO needs to be there from photo.SE, if it needs to move from photo.SE to Meta.SO it can (and probably should) take a trip through meta.photo.SE first. The rest of the list gets a +1 from me!

Answer (score 0):

Reid brought up an interesting note on the comments of that thread. He was essentially asking what the difference was between the question "How do I wirelessly transfer photos from my iPhone 4" vs. "How do I transfer photos off of my Nikon camera."

I do think there is a distinction between the two. With the former, while the data involved are photographs, the question is not specifically related to photography...it is an iPhone 4/Wifi question, a topic which definitely belongs on superuser.com. The same exact question could be made for an iPhone 4 for any kind of data, not just photographs. It ***may*** be on-topic here, but it is definitely on-topic at superuser.

The latter, transferring photos off of a Nikon camera, while similar in nature, is that it is on-topic here (it specifically deals with a camera and can only involve the transfer of photographs), <strike>but probably off-topic at superuser.</strike>

On further thought, such a question about a Nikon camera is still probably on-topic at superuser.com.

Comment: Since this question is about what to do with off-topic questions, and I believe there's a valid discussion about whether that particular question is on-topic, I created another meta question: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/108/questions-about-devices-which-take-pictures-but-where-the-camera-is-not-the-fir

Comment: If someone asked how to send a text with their iPhone on a "mobile phone site", would it be a valid response to send them to superuser because their iPhone has a camera in it?

Comment: @Reuscam: My point is less about it being off-topic, and more about where it is best likely to get useful answers. I think it also boils down to what we really consider the scope of this site. Is it a site about photography and photographic editing...or do we want to include photography hardware troubleshooting to the list as well? If we do, then that changes the argument entirely.

Comment: Let me clarify "photography hardware troubleshooting", as that will probably be misinterperated. Do we want this site to be a site for "photography" in the sense of theory, application, and image development...or do we want it to be a site where people come to ask questions about how to get their hardware talking to each other? We could have a zillion questions about connecting iPhones to Macs and Point and Shoot cameras to Windows...but is that what we really want? Personally, I look forward to discussions about PHOTOGRAPHY...I can always go to SuperUser for the other stuff.

Comment: I understand where you're going, and I don't disagree necessarily.  I am concerned, however, about the probably lack of content 6 months down the road once all the straightforward questions are asked.  Photography is a much more subjective topic than programming, so if we take the stack overflow approach to manage discussions, we might end up with a barren landscape.  I know that the question we're talking about isn't a subjective one, but I've been thinking about this as a problem because of this topic, and thought I would mention it.

Comment: I think thats a good point to make. I don't want to see the site die due to lack of content. I'd be willing to cover hardware troubleshooting too.