# Migrate off-topic questions

Tags: feature-request, off-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a migration path → superuser, graphicdesign, and avp, please?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/690/can-we-have-a-migration-path-superuser-graphicdesign-and-avp-please)

[This question](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103/move-off-topic-questions) was asked over a year ago, about giving some options to migrate questions when they are off-topic, rather than just closing them.  The accepted answer on that question seems out of date (The D-SLR Video proposal has expired for example).  There are however some questions that are coming up that could be migrated to other sites.

For example it was suggested that [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17499/are-there-any-camcorders-with-high-quality-like-nikon-d3100-without-its-time-lim) could be migrated to avp.stackexchange.com, where as [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17438/need-a-image-manipulation-program) could have gone to Graphic Design.  I haven't been following the site for that long, but it does seem like there are some candidates for repeated question migration.  This would help us work better with the rest of the network and help people get answers to their questions.  Can we identify some of the most likely destinations (I believe there are four slots left, since one is currently used for Meta) and get them implemented?

Comment: @mattdm: You're right, totally missed that one when I looked.